# React native launches first launch screen repeatedly

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I have created app in react native with a screen that will appear only on first app entry.
Other times it just load it [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) value to check if the app has been launched before.

The screen does appear, but on every app launch. I want it to appear only on first launch.

As far as I know the following code should work, but something collapsing here with the `async` probably..

```
export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  const verifyHasLaunched = async () => {
    try {
      const hasLaunched = await AsyncStorage.getItem(HAS_LAUNCHED);
      if(hasLaunched){
        setSelected(true);
      }
      setSelected(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setSelected(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => verifyHasLaunched, []);

  //The rest of the code - irrelevant
  //By using Selected state I show different screen and not first launch screen.
```

**CheckIfFirstLaunch function**

```
//Save the language as AsyncStorage for other times the user will open the app
async function setAppLaunched(en) {
  AsyncStorage.setItem(HAS_LAUNCHED, "true");
  AsyncStorage.setItem(en ? ENGLISH : HEBREW, "true");
  if(await AsyncStorage.getItem(HEBREW)){
    i18n.locale = "he";
    I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
  }
  else{
    i18n.locale = "en";
    I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
  }
}


//If first launch show this screen
function CheckIfFirstLaunch({ onSelect }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const selectLaunched = (value) => {
    if(value){
      i18n.locale = "en";
      I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
    }
    else{
      i18n.locale = "he";
      I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
    }
    setAppLaunched(value);
    onSelect();
    navigation.navigate('Login');
  };


  return (
    <View>
        <Text>Choose Language</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => selectLaunched(false)} title="Hebrew"/>
        <Button onPress={() => selectLaunched(true)} title="English"/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Expected behavior**

`CheckIfFirstLaunch()` should appear only once on first launch.

**Current behavior**

`CheckIfFirstLaunch()` appears on every launch.

How can I create React Native first launch screen correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(hasLaunched){
        setSelected(true);
} else {
      setSelected(false);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, although nice catch, it would of been my next error

Comment: Is ```hasLaunched``` a boolean or a string ?

Comment: This is the initial set: `const HAS_LAUNCHED = "hasLaunched";` after that it's changed to `"true"` as you can see in the code

Comment: I mean you are using a string as a boolean ( a condition in if clause). By the way, would you mind logging its value?

Comment: `hasLaunched` is boolean, now that I run `console.log(hasLaunched);` I get no value in the console, but if I refresh the app I receive true.